# Oracle SQL How to create an update script from a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have this select statement;

```
select 
   I.itemno,
   avg(D.unit_price) as average 
from 
   INVENTORY I, 
   ORDER_DTL D 
where 
   I.id = D.INVENTORY_ID 
   group by I.itemno;
```

There is another column in the INVENTORY table that I wish to update with the average sales price.
Is there a way to do this in one statement?

Thanks
James

Comment: Can't you have a staging table (GTT or some temp table) and then update using a [correlated subquery](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/06/27/correlated-update-statement/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE INVENTORY A SET avg_price = 
(select 
   avg(D.unit_price) as average 
from 
   INVENTORY I, 
   ORDER_DTL D 
where 
   I.id = D.INVENTORY_ID 
 AND I.itemno = A.itemno
   group by I.itemno);
```

Wont this help ??

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1349/2)

Comment: This will update the whole table with the avg price. I believe his intention is to update the avg within the groupings of id. May be OP can confirm. You may try to gather the set in a Oracle Key Preserved view and update the same by forcing a index on base tables 
before the update.

Comment: Good Thing for rollback,  Ran the above script and just as "real" has stated.  This script should have update about 500 rows.  However it updated all items.  Its fine tho as after reading your script I wanted to put up a test system. Thanks Mr Fiddle!